# JDBC bulk data load/unload tool to work with Oracle, H2

Tags: windows, database, jdbc

Not looking for a complex ETL tool or anything like that. What I need is a tool that will do the following :-

- Connect to an Oracle database and dump contents of all tables (must be able to ask the DB itself to determine all tables in specified schema) into either a set of files or a single file - I don't care about the format or compression, I just want to dump the table data. A binary format might be preferable to avoid quoting/character set issues.
- Connect to another database (Oracle or H2), and insert from the file(s) into the tables in the target database.

Ideally:

- Programmatically disable all constraints, truncate all tables, then insert data, and finally enable all constraints again

Platform:

- Must run on Windows
- Must have a command-line interface so it can be scripted
- Can be free/open-source/commercial, don't care

It's the sort of thing I know I can write myself, but would inevitable take longer than I estimate...